# AWS network ELB session stickiness

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, https

I have an AWS network ELB listening on & forwarding to TCP 443, and I have a requirement to use sticky sessions with this load balancer. According to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) it appears to be possible to achieve this by simply setting the target group 'stickiness' atttribute to 'Enabled' which I have done, however when testing with curl this load balancer still appears to be distributing consecutive requests from the same host to all the servers behind the load balancer. Is there anything else I need to do to enable stickiness? Unfortunately I cannot use an Application ELB due to organisational constraints.

Comment: Is your listener's protocol TCP or TLS? Have you assigned an SSL certificate to your listener?

Comment: Hi, the protocol is TCP so I have not assigned an SSL cert.

Comment: I vaguely recall having a similar problem in the past. I recall the answer being enabling cross zone load balancing. This might not solve your problem, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this & can confirm that target group stickiness does work the way it's supposed to. Please check the following in your test setup:

- Is it possible that the public IP of your client changed during the test? This is the system where you ran curl. Stickiness is tied to the client IP. If the client IP changes, its requests might go to another server.
- Did the healthy status of any of your backend instances change during the test. This might reset the target group's stickiness.
- Did any instance join or leave the target group during the test, either manually or by an auto scaling group? This might reset the target group's stickiness.
- Are both the listener's & target group's protocol TCP (not TLS)? [AWS ELB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) says:

> Sticky sessions are not supported with TLS listeners and TLS target groups.

- Reconfirm that stickiness is indeed enabled on the target group. You can check this by opening the target group in the EC2 console:

[image]

---

For the record, here's my test setup:

- 1 Network LB & 2 `t2.micro`s in ap-south-1b.
- NGINX running on both instances, reconfigured to listen for HTTP (not HTTPS) traffic on port 443.
- 1 listener for the NLB listening for TCP (not TLS) traffic on port 443 & forwarding it to port 443 of the target group.
- Tested with target groups with target types of both instance & IP. As long as they had stickiness enabled, the client traffic kept going to the same instance.